# How to find AVERAGE of temperature values on hourly basis in MySQL. Also how to calculate average temp on 3hour, 6hr, 9hr and 12hr basis?

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I am using Raspberry Pi and DHT11 to log temperature and humidity data in **MySQL database** at every 5 minutes.

```
MariaDB [measurements]> desc measurements;
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ttime       | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| temperature | float(4,1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| humidity    | float(4,1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

```
MariaDB [measurements]> select * from measurements order by ttime limit 10;
+---------------------+-------------+----------+
| ttime               | temperature | humidity |
+---------------------+-------------+----------+
| 2021-01-06 22:10:03 |        28.0 |     59.0 |
| 2021-01-06 22:14:56 |        30.0 |     52.0 |
| 2021-01-06 22:19:47 |        30.0 |     93.0 |
| 2021-01-06 22:54:39 |        28.0 |     57.0 |
| 2021-01-06 23:16:51 |        27.0 |     59.0 |
| 2021-01-06 23:18:04 |        28.0 |     60.0 |
| 2021-01-06 23:19:36 |        27.0 |     59.0 |
| 2021-01-06 23:21:16 |        27.0 |     59.0 |
| 2021-01-07 00:35:39 |        28.0 |     60.0 |
| 2021-01-07 00:37:03 |        27.0 |     60.0 |
+---------------------+-------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

I am able to find AVERAGE of temperature for **each day**, based on following code:

```
MariaDB [measurements]> select avg(temperature),datediff(sysdate(),ttime) diff
    -> from measurements 
    -> group by diff
    -> order by ttime desc limit 10;
+------------------+------+
| avg(temperature) | diff |
+------------------+------+
|         25.25000 |    0 |
|         26.02041 |    1 |
|         27.00000 |    2 |
|         26.00000 |    3 |
|         26.26490 |    4 |
|         26.08187 |    5 |
|         27.33333 |    6 |
|         28.12500 |    7 |
+------------------+------+
8 rows in set (0.010 sec)
```

I want to get average temperature on **hourly basis** so the output can be as follows:
(For Example, the first reading is 2021-01-06 at 10 AM and average temperature is 28.0. This average is calculated based on readings taken between 9:00 AM and 10:00 AM)

```
Expected output:
+---------------------+-------------+
| ttime               | AVG Temp    | 
+---------------------+-------------+
| 2021-01-06 10:00:00 |        28.0 |    
| 2021-01-06 09:00:00 |        30.0 |     
| 2021-01-06 08:00:00 |        30.0 |    
| 2021-01-06 07:00:00 |        28.0 |     
| 2021-01-06 06:00:00 |        27.0 |     
| 2021-01-06 05:00:00 |        28.0 |    
| 2021-01-06 04:00:00 |        27.0 |    
| 2021-01-06 03:00:00 |        27.0 |    
| 2021-01-06 02:00:00 |        28.0 |    
| 2021-01-06 01:00:00 |        27.0 |     
+---------------------+-------------+
```

For each hour, there will be  (60 minutes / 5 minutes) = 12 readings. So each row of output contains average of maximum 12 readings.

I know the **timediff** command, but not sure how this will be helpful.

```sql
MariaDB [measurements]> select timediff(sysdate(), ttime)
    -> from measurements
    -> order by ttime
    -> desc
    -> limit 10;
+----------------------------+
| timediff(sysdate(), ttime) |
+----------------------------+
| 00:02:28                   |
| 00:07:28                   |
| 00:12:28                   |
| 00:17:28                   |
| 00:22:28                   |
| 00:27:28                   |
| 00:32:26                   |
| 00:37:28                   |
| 00:42:28                   |
| 00:47:28                   |
+----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.005 sec)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the `HOUR()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use hour()

```
select avg(temperature),date(ttime), hour(ttime)
 from measurements 
 group by date(ttime),  hour(ttime)
 order by date(ttime) desc, hour(ttime) desc limit 10;
```